# remote desktop out of ram and swap memory

Tags: python, linux, ssh, swap, ram

I launched some python script on a remote desktop PC via ssh. The system is running ubuntu 14.04. There were some bugs in my script and they filled all the ram (and also the swap I think) of the remote desktop.
Now the desktop is blocked, it takes about 15 minutes to ssh connect to it (normally this operation was lasting few seconds) and then also typing a command in the terminal takes about 20 seconds per letter.

I tried to type

```
killall -9 python
```

(it took me about 5 minutes to write this command letter by letter since the system is litelally blocked).
I typed that command about 40 minutes ago and nothing has changes.
Has anyone an idea about how I could kill all the process I launched or force the freeing of the memory in order to recover the control of the remote desktop?

Comment: Can you just get someone physically near the PC to turn it off and on?

Comment: Well, you're going to have to run `ps x` to get the running processes, then run `kill -9 PID` where PID is the process id of your script. Alternatively, just run `sudo shutdown -r now` to remotely reboot the system.